# Rails not logging requests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, docker, logging

I'm *utterly* stumped as to why I'm not able to see the Rails controller outputs in my development log. I've spent days beating my head against a wall trying to figure this out and I'm not sure what else to try.

**Setup:** Rails `5.2.3` app running ruby `2.6.3` via `docker-compose`.

It started with me not being able to see my app logs when running `docker logs <container-name>`. However, I soon realized that I was able to see the output from `puma` starting and a `shell` script that ran `rake` tasks that the issue might be with `rails`.

To help assist with finding the issue:

- Tore down and rebuilt the docker environment, *several times*
- Stopped writing via `STDOUT` in favor of `logs/development.log`
- Disabled `lograge` and `elastic-apm`, just in case
- Reverted my `development.rb` config back to what's generated with a `rails new`
- Followed the suggestions [here](https://blog.eq8.eu/til/ruby-logs-and-puts-not-shown-in-docker-container-logs.html)

However, when running the rails console via `docker exec -it <container-name>`:

- Running `Rails.logger.level` returns `2` which is `warn`, despite the default logging level being `dev`
- I'm able to see log output when running `Rails.logger.warn 'foo'`
- After setting `Rails.logger.level = 0` I'm able to see output when running `Rails.logger.debug 'foo'`

I tried setting the value explicitly as `config.log_level = :debug` in `development.rb` yet it still set itself to the `warn` level.

However, I'm still not able to see any logs when navigating the application. Any thoughts?

Comment: how you start you application in Dockerfile? better to post your dockerfile

Comment: @Adiii I don't think that has anything to do with it but my docker-compose command is `"bundle", "exec", "rails", "s", "-b", "0.0.0.0", "-p", "5000"`

Comment: I'd take a look at [this](https://blog.eq8.eu/til/ruby-logs-and-puts-not-shown-in-docker-container-logs.html).

Comment: @MarkMerritt, sorry I should have mentioned that tried that as well. If you look in the comments, I'm the Justin Adkins that commented the other day lol. Since that wasn't able to solve my problem, it led me to believe the the issue wasn't with docker but with rails itself. Docker is picking up logs just fine. It seems rails isn't outputting them correctly for some reason.

Answer (score 2):

Ugh. I feel like the biggest schmuck but I've figured out the issue.

I went back though source-control to see what has changed recently. In addition to the `elastic-apm` gem, I also added the [Unleash](https://github.com/Unleash/unleash-client-ruby) gem.

I went to check out it's configuration and it looks like following their recommenced [configuration](https://github.com/Unleash/unleash-client-ruby/blob/master/README.md#add-initializer) causes logging to break. The line that was specifically causing offense was in the unleash initializer setting `config.logger = Rails.logger`